# Swift and NSCoding: Encoding an array of objects conforming to a class-only protocol

Tags: arrays, swift, protocols, nscoding

I have a class, `StandardObject`, that conforms to the protocol `Object`. Another class, `ObjectManager`, has a property called `objects` which is an array containing instances of `Object`. Both `StandardObject` and `ObjectManager` are subclasses of `NSObject` and conform to `NSCoding`.

When I try to encode the `objects` property of `ObjectManager` in `encodeWithCoder:`, I receive an error:

```
cannot convert value of type '[Object]' to expected argument type 'AnyObject?'
```

Here is my code:

`ObjectManager`:

```
class ObjectManager: NSObject, NSCoding {

    var objects = [Object]()

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {

    }

    func encodeWithCoder(aCoder: NSCoder) {
        aCoder.encodeObject(objects, forKey: "Objects") //// ERROR HERE
    }

}
```

`Object` protocol:

```
protocol Object: class, NSCoding {
    // Currently completely empty
}
```

`StandardObject`:

```
class StandardObject: NSObject, Object {

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {

    }

    func encodeWithCoder(aCoder: NSCoder) {

    }

}
```

I know it has to do with the fact that you can only encode objects (or arrays of them), not structs, enums, or in this case, protocols. However, the `Object` protocol's declaration is:

```
protocol Object: class, NSCoding
```

which means that only classes can conform to this protocol.

Shouldn't that mean that there are only instances of classes in the `objects` array? Why can't it be encoded?

I have also tried casting the array to an NSArray before encoding, but I get this error:

```
cannot convert value of type '[Object]' to type 'NSArray' in coercion
```

So here are my two questions:

1. If I made the `Object` protocol only have objects conform to it, shouldn't an array of `Object` be an array of objects?
2. If question 1 isn't possible for some reason, how do you convert the array of `Object` to be able to be encoded with `NSCoding`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to declare your protocol as `@objc`, to place it into the `Objective-C` world:

```
@objc protocol Object: class, NSCoding {
```

The compiler will then know he will be able to toll-free bridge the Swift array with a `NSArray`, as you'll be able to build-up the array only with instances of classes derived from `NSObject`.